# auto submit won't run

Tags: javascript, html, forms

edit: change of question

if my code is like this:

```
<form name="login" action="https://login.extremebb.net/login" method="post"

                >

                <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="/status.html" />

                    <label for="username"><b>Username: </b></label>

                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" value="" size="23" />

                    <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>

                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" size="23" />

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/status.html"/>

                </form>
```

what should i do to make it auto submit after page load or a set of time?

note: saved username and password in browser

Comment: You want the form to be submitted as soon as the page loads?

Comment: yes, i want it to be submitted as soon as the page loads. there is something i want to try about it

Comment: Would you like to have jQuery solution?

Comment: If using as document.subfrm, Form must have id attribute

Comment: llia Rostovtsev, by how you mean? i prefer a clean solution such as the line i used in the code

Comment: jQuery has a .ready() event, which means to fire it right after the page (DOM) loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<body onload="document.getElementById('submit').click()">
    <form name="subfrm" action="../New%20folder%20(3)/success.html">
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="/success.html" />
        <label for="username"><b>Username: </b></label>
        <input class="field" type="text" name="username" value="" size="23" />
        <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input class="field" type="password" name="password" size="23" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="../New%20folder%20(3)/success.html"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is at your **submit button** which has `name="submit"`! Changed it to `ANYTHING_ELSE` and worked!

```
<body onload="document.subfrm.submit();">
    <form name="subfrm"  action="../New%20folder%20(3)/success.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="/success.html" />
    <label for="username">
        <b>Username: </b>
    </label>
    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" value="" size="23" />
    <label for="password">
        <b>Password:</b></label>
    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" size="23" />
    <input type="submit" name="ANYTHING_ELSE" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="../New%20folder%20(3)/success.html" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can click the submit button manually, but you need to give it an id to use getElementById.  I am not sure, but I think the document.[name of element] is not cross browser compliant.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('submitButton').click();"  >
    <form id="subfrm"  name="subfrm" action="/Quantifi/" >
        <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="/success.html" />
        <label for="username"><b>Username: </b></label>
        <input class="field" type="text" name="username" value="" size="23" />
        <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
        <input class="field" type="password" name="password" size="23" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/Quantifi"/>
    </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: as others have mentioned, naming your submit button "submit" also causes problems.  If you give the button and id/name of something else, the following would work on the onload event:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('subfrm').submit();"  >
```